# Compare two archive files BashShell

Tags: bash, shell, compare, archive

I'm new in Bash and I need help.

I need to create a shell script that shall compare two gzipped archives. For each file or directory in each archive file (even in archived subdirectories), the script shall verify whether a file/directory of the same name exists in the other archive. In case of a missing directory, ignore missing files or subdirectories within this directory. The script shall list the names of all files which do not have a matching equivalent in the other archive.

The output of script when comparing archives **arch1.tar.gz and archive2.tar.gz** and finding differing files **aa/a.txt, bb/b.txt** in **archive.tar.gz and c.txt v arch2.tar.gz**:

> arch1.tar.gz:aa/a.txt
>
> arch1.tar.gz:bb/b.txt
>
> arch2.tar.gz:c.txt

Here what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
$2

tar tf $1>> list1.txt
tar tf $2>> list2.txt
comm -23 <(sort list1.txt -o list1.txt | uniq) <(sort list2.txt -o list2.txt| uniq)
diff list1.txt list2.txt>>contestboth
```

The thing is that I can't image anything for output.

Comment: If you use `-o` to sort then it doesn't write to standard output so those `| uniq` pipelines cannot possibly be working. Additionally those first two lines `$1` and `$2` are attempting to execute the first and second arguments to the script as commands which likely isn't what you wanted (if there even are arguments to the script which it doesn't appear that their are). That being said I don't understand what your final sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: Using option `-o` makes no sense in combination with piping the output to `uniq`.  You should probably just use `sort -u` which already does the uniq feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
diff <(sort -u list1.txt) <(sort -u list2.txt)
```

By this two sub processes are started (the two `sort` commands) and their output is associated with file descriptors.  The syntax `<(...)` returns a file name representing this file descriptor (something like `/dev/fd/63`).  So in the end, `diff` is called with two files which, when read, (seem to) contain the output of the two processes.

This method works fine for programs which read a file strictly linearly.  Seeking in the "file" is not possible, of course.

Comment: You may want to add a description of how this command works. As it stands, this is not a great answer.

Comment: Yeah, I explained it a little.